# Como hago que cuando de el 2do click y encuentre la clase active, la elimine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Como hago que cuando de el 2do click y encuentre la clase `active`, la elimine

```
$('.siniestros button').click(function () {

    $('.siniestros>button>.before').addClass('active');

    $('.siniestros>.preguntas').slideToggle('fast',function(){

    });


})
```

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendi lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar esto:

```
$('.siniestros button').click(function () {

    $('.siniestros>button>.before').toggleClass('active');

    $('.siniestros>.preguntas').slideToggle('fast',function(){

    });

})
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvio mucho